# "ActivityManagerService: Task to front request from 10299 stopped " while running moveTaskToFront

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a notification in my notification bar, onclick of that notification my application should come to front from the recent apps. I am using the "moveTaskToFront()" to achieve this. but I am getting the warning "Task to front request from 10299 stopped" and the task not coming to front. below is the code that I am using for this task.

```
private void moveTaskToFront() {
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        if(recentTasks!=null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) {
                if (recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toString().contains(UDR.PACKAGE_SHEALTH)) {
                    activityManager.moveTaskToFront(recentTasks.get(i).id, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also I have the permissons declared in my manifest below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```